# Chrome Extension Content Scripts Matches Answers

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

```
"content_scripts":[{
                    "matches" : ["*"],
                    "js": ["jquery-2.0.2.min.js","jquery.Jcrop.js"],
                    "css": ["jquery.Jcrop.min.css"]
    }],
```

For my chrome extension, I want it to work on all pages, and inject that code into all pages. How can I do this? Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [match pattern documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html), the URLs in `matches` have to follow this pattern:

```
<url-pattern> := <scheme>://<host><path>
```

Yours is therefore invalid, since it's missing `://` as well as the `host` and `path` part.
You can use the special pattern `<all_urls>` to inject your script on all the supported schemes:

```
"content_scripts":[{
                "matches" : [ "<all_urls>" ],
                "js": ["jquery-2.0.2.min.js","jquery.Jcrop.js"],
                "css": ["jquery.Jcrop.min.css"]
}],
```

**Important note:** the supported schemes are `http`, `https`, `file`, `ftp`, and `chrome-extension`; it means that you can't inject your script in any of the `chrome://` URLs.

Comment: odd thing is that even when I include "query.js", i still get the error "$ is not defined" which basically means that jquery.js is not being read :(